# Difference / Benefits of the below React methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm fairly new to ReactJS and have been learning a bit and JSX. I'm converting my personal website from HTML/JS to React.

What is the difference in using for example:

```
React.createElement("div", {className: "row"}, ------)
```

and in JSX (with a corresponding component of "LayoutRowDiv.js" doing the exact above, really.

```
<LayoutRowDiv> ------------- </LayoutRowDiv>
```

Which would be best practice? I've coded a bit of my homepage using both methods and to be honest, the first version looks cleaner?

Just looking some opinions and thoughts as maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

I've attached both the snippets.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSX is just a syntatic sugar over React.createElement with no added functionality. Its is more of a developer preference on which should be used. Apart from the fact that you would be saving a few babel modules and steps during build time which is close to negligible impact to performance if you chose `React.createElement`, I would say both fare the same.

Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: This is brilliant - Exactly what i wanted to hear. I thought I was going crazy thinking which I should use. I obviously understand that some Elements would be better as a component to reduce code duplication. Thank you for your answer, completely set my mind at peace now!